# What kinds of visual content, tables or diagrams might I want to include in my Project Architecture Document?

Tags: architecture, documentation, communication, organization, diagrams

Besides logical and physical architecture diagrams, comps / mockups and tables for expected network load between components and various data schemas, what kinds of visual content, tables or diagrams might I want to include in my Project Architecture Document?

The specific project is an integration of 3rd party social networking features into a fashion site.

Please post example graphics. Thanks.

Comment: I think mixing the 2 is bad for security (social media and eCommerce)

Answer (score 12):

When it comes to architecture it always depends. When building a simple throw away application you document way less than when building a large service oriented architecture. When building an application in an agile organisation you document less then when building an application in a highly governed waterfall organisation.

When it comes to determining what to use I like the [IEEE 1471](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CGUQFjAD&url=http://www.win.tue.nl/~johanl/educ/2II45/Lit/software-architecture-std1471-2000.pdf&ei=N0wxUMDlJeiw0QX7-YHoDA&usg=AFQjCNFv2VWDafP-Zp5rs-eDfZ6CmOL9FA&cad=rja) way of thinking

[image: parts in IEEE 1471]

(image from http://iea.wikidot.com/ieee1471 )

Look at your stakeholders, determine their concerns, identify the viewpoints which best describe how your architecture addresses the concerns, describe these viewpoints.

As an alternative and a more common way the "[4+1 Architectural View Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4+1_Architectural_View_Model)" addresses the need for a lot of projects.

What you probably did not mean, but which could give you also some new ways of thinking about it is the [PSA (Project start architecture)](http://www.via-nova-architectura.org/files/TEAR2007/Foorthuis.pdf). Which is more of an enterprise architecture document. A great presentation on the PSA and how it fits into [TOGAF](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ar-togaf2/) can be found [here](https://collaboration.opengroup.org/conference-live/uploads/40/19375/PSA_as_killer_application_for_EA_final_29April2009.pdf) (pdf)

A great book that also give a lot of insights on how to describe software architectures is "[Software Architecture in practice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321154959)" ( [third edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321815734) coming out soon)

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: +1 for the reference to "Software Architecture in practice".

Comment: I like this answer but it is important to note that the documentation requirements will vary with the complexity and size of the project. Doing a 100+ page design for a small, simple project is just wasting the architect's time. Produce enough documentation you need for a successful project and no more.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the 4+1 Architectural View Model:

[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%2B1_Architectural_View_Model)

[Original paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gregor/teaching/papers/4+1view-architecture.pdf)

I find it inspiring for answering the kind of questions you are probably looking after. Adapt to your needs.